# How do I copy a TimeMachine backup to an encrypted disk?

Tags: macos, time-machine, filevault

I want to replace my current TimeMachine backup disk with a new disk, but I also want to copy the existing contents to the new disk after encrypting the new disk.

How can I best do that? Are there any pitfalls waiting for me?

Answer (score 2):

Apple has some instructions in this [KB](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5096). There are some restrictions - Apple suggests that you'll need to format the new drive as `Mac OS Extended` with a `GUID` partition.

Short summary:

> Drag the folder `"Backups.backupdb"` on the current backup drive to the
>   root level of the new backup drive.

Follow the other instructions in the KB, and you'll be able to use your new drive as the TimeMachine drive.